# ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried to install the module **flask-sqlalchemy** to my flask application, typing the following command : *pipenv install flask-sqlalchemy*.
Then I received the following return :

```
(auth) ➜  flask_auth_app pipenv install flask-sqlalchemy
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Installing flask-sqlalchemy...
WARNING: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc1' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
✘ Installation Failed
```

What this means and how can I fix it ?

Comment: It means what it says: The character at hand isn't 7-bit-ASCII clean. (_Which_ character this is would require digging deeper into exactly which code threw the exception; I'd suggest starting by looking at relevant directory names, usernames, etc -- if you have any high-ASCII or multi-byte characters in the above, those are the place to start).

Comment: BTW, this isn't in any way a terminal problem -- you'd have the same failure if your stdin were connected to `/dev/null` and stdout and stderr went to files, with no terminal involved anywhere at all. As such, the terminal tag can be removed.

Comment: (This would be easier to fix if whoever's setup-time code has an `except:` block catching the error and throwing a warning would preserve the stack trace; it's conceivable that there might be an environment variable to make it do just that, but you'd need to identify the point-of-failure to determine what and where that is; that said, you could potentially use `python -m trace` to run `pipenv` with its execution logged, to track down the relevant code that way).